# How do I add applications to Pinned in the Steam Context Menu on the Taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, context-menu, steam

I have Steam on my Taskbar, right clicking it opens this menu:

[image]

How can I add applications to this list (Indicated by the red arrow)? I tried marking as favorite on steam but it didn't do anything. I can't find a Pin option within Steam. Is there a folder where these shortcuts are contained such that I can put something there?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You may not have gotten a notification for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steam's ***Pinned*** section simply lists your most recently played games. In fact, the section was renamed to ***Recent*** in an update not too long ago.

Unfortunately, this means there really isn't a way to manually add games to this list.

[image: Steam's recent list]